# Windows Snipping Tool image pasted into Word gets destroyed when Calc'ing with F9

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool, microsoft-word-2019

When I Copy an image with the Snipping Tool (built into Windows 10) and paste into a Word document, then highlight the image, then press F9 (Calc), Word makes the image unreadable and the embedded image is replaced with the following message: ‘The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.’ It feels like somehow Word thinks the image being pasted is a link to a file. How can I embed the image so that recalcing all fields (Ctrl+A, then F9) in the document will not destroy the image?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Unbelievable, but I can duplicate what you describe. However, when I paste-in from the Snipping Tool, this doesn't happen. Are you pasting using anything else than just Ctrl+V? Do you edit first the image in any way?

Comment: Hi Harry, Thanks for your effort. Now I cannot seem to duplicate the problem. The problem is evident in the file that I showed you, however, when I copy an image from the Snipping Tool and paste it into that same Word document, F9 does not seem to destroy the graphic. So, something must be happening to that file after I paste the image to cause the problem. I will research and carefully and post again here. I may need some time.

Comment: Perhaps a one-time occurrence caused by a missed click. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Hello @harrymc  I did more testing and possibly figured out the source of the problem. I wrote the following guidance:
Copying an image from an email to a document
>Do this by undertaking each following action:
>>Use the Snipping Tool to make a copy of the image within the email.
>>Paste the clipboard into the document.
>Do not copy the image from the email directly (using e.g., 1) Ctrl +C or 2) right click, then copy), because such image is unstable and will be lost when the pasted image is updated using F9.

Comment: FYI: The same happened to me while editing an old (existing) doc file: after doing a few changes and then ctrl-a F9 I saved the file. Then upon reopening, I noticed two images (but not the others) are replaced with the same error message as in question. My solution: as I still had the old version of the file, I just copy-pasted these two images from the old doc into the new one (replacing the broken images).

Comment: I ran into the same issue today and I believe the problem stems from duplicating a Word document, or saving separate versions of one. The second copy of the file appears to exhibit the issue, but not the first.

Comment: Additionally, the individual images that fail to display happen to be those that were originally pasted into the original document from an Outlook email message.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the issue. I copied an image from outlook into word and F9 leads to issue "The linked image cannot be displayed.".
As workaround I copy the image from word to paint.net and back into word, then the issue is resolved. There seems to be an obscure connection between Outlook images and word, which leads to the broken images on update with F9.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).